# PHP Calling methods of class that was defined as a member of this class? mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to setup a PDO connection to replace my standard mysql connection. Until now I have a class called DB_Class that has in it's constructor the typical mysql_connect, mysql_select_db... stuff.

I use it by creating a new instance of DB_Class in the constructor of each of my objects that will hit the DB. I got the example online somewhere and it seems to work.

Now I want to switch to PDO and I am trying the same logic here but it is not working as I'd hoped. Here is what I have.

```
class DB_Class {
    function __construct() {
        //$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or
        //        die('Oops connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
        //mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());

        $dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";port=".DB_PORT." dbname=" . DB_DATABASE;
        $dbConnection = new PDO($dbConnString, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        //$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_DATABASE.';host='.DB_SERVER.';charset=utf8', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

Here is the Constructor of my client  class

```
//Initialize the DB Class 
    public function __construct() {
        $db = new DB_Class();
    }
```

Here is where I am not quite sure how to use it?

```
public function FindByOwnerID($id) {
        $clients = array();       

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Client WHERE OwnerID = :id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I did not create a member variable on the DB_Class so that I could access the connection form a Class using DB_Class. Now that I have the $dbConnection as a member variable I am able to make my connection and all is good.

Comment: He probably doesn't know how to proxy method calls from his `DB_Class` to the PDO object.

Comment: glad you figured it out. hopefully next time you'll remember to check the error log first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor should be

```
$this->db = new DB_Class();
^^^^^^^^^
```

`$db` by itself is merely a local variable within that method. You need to assign it as an object attribute, which is `$this->whatever`.

Same goes wherever you use `$db` in the other methods, it should always be `$this->db`.